# Delete a database in Redis with Python

Tags: python, caching, redis

I created two databases with my Python script. I see that a user can remove a database through the "Databases page", but I want to delete the database when closing my application
I am able to clean the database with flushdb(), but is there a way to remove the database itself using python?

Comment: You CANNOT delete a database in Redis, but only delete all keys in a given database, i.e. use `FLUSHDB` command.

Comment: Is there a way to access a previously created database from another program?

Comment: You can use the `SELECT` command to access the database by database index.